# Is request / response messages are encrypted with TransportWithMessageCredential?

Tags: wcf, security, ws-security

Message level security encrypts request / response messages using WS-Security specifications and provides end-to-end security. This I understood correctly. 
My Q is: 
do weget same level of security as above when using TransportWithMessageCredential mode. I means Encrypts request/response message( including Message body)

Answer (score 0):

TransportWithMessageCredential encrypts the entire transmission from point to point is HTTPs/SSL encrypted for both the request and response, while message-level encryption encrypts the content of the message, basically leaving the header information intact, but the body of the message unreadable.

In addition, TransportWithMessageCredential puts an client authentication information (ID/Password, client certificate, etc.) inside the body of the message so that the tasks of encryption and authentication can be separated into two steps.

Comment: When Message level Encryption happens with TransportWithMessageCredential Why don't we consider TransportWithMessageCredential  as End to End protection?

Comment: Message encryption is OK as long as your talking about server-to-server communication. With SSL, the host sends the public key of the certificate to the client and then the communication begins. With Message encryption, public key of the encrypting cert must be INSTALLED by an administrator on both machines, plus the private key on the host. That's OK when only a couple of servers are involved, but if you're planning Message encryption on a larger scale, you'll have trouble managing the certificate distribution/management.